# Storing User data in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

How to store state information for a user on a channel and use it throughout for latter conversations in bot framework?
Where should I call `SetUserData()`? Inside one of my dialogs (what if this dialog is not called) or MessageController?

Comment: For more information, check out the article: [Managing State Data in Bot Framework .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [The Bot State service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-state) enables your bot to store and retrieve state
>   data that is associated with a user, a conversation, or a specific
>   user within the context of a specific conversation.

In order to **store** some data:

```
IDialogContext cxt;
cxt.UserData.SetValue(key, value);
```

And later you can **retrieve** with:

```
IDialogContext cxt;
string result;
cxt.UserData.TryGetValue(key, out result);
```